# Only two machines in lan asking for credentials

Tags: windows-8.1, network-shares

[image]

Our straightforward network depicted. Woodcutter, Renat and Encad are win 8.1 machines, activated and fully updated, others are win 7. All computers are in the same subnet, Workgroup. Firewalls turned off, no antiviruses, only Windows Defender. User accounts without passwords, exclude Encad machine (laptop).

All sharing options set to Read-Write for Everyone. I can open Woodcutter shares from Lecai, Renat, Grafrtec and vice versa, I can open Encad shares from Lecai, Renat, Grafrtec and vice versa.

And it asking to enter credentials for Woodcutter to Encad and Encad to Woodcutter. What can be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The owner of Encad and Woodcutter is the same person, and both accounts was created with the same name. Later Encad account was renamed, but not properly, only shown name was changed. Thus renaming Encad user accoount in proper way solved the issue